# How to prevent formatting a USB drive partition?

Tags: windows, partitioning, formatting, liveusb

I have installed Ubuntu on my USB drive. Currently, it holds 4 partitions:

- /dev/sda1 - fat32 mounted on /boot/efi
- /dev/sda2 - swap
- /dev/sda3 - ext4 mounted on /
- /dev/sda4 - ntsf for working with windows

I want the first 3 partitions (EFI, swap, and ext4) to be hidden from **any** Windows pc because it asks users to format them, which will break the installation.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Image of [partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOto3.png) in GParted.

Comment: Have you tried "hidden" partitions?

Comment: I suggest you switch around the partitions so the NTFS partition comes first. This is also suitable for legacy Windows behavior. Other than that, check [this answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/592498/118751).

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, I tried to set flag hidden in GParted. Didn't work.

Comment: @DanielB, can I do it, while working from that USB?

Comment: No, that’s totally impossible.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to use another pc with Linux. But how do I rearrange them?